# Electrum server method: "blockchain.scripthash.subscribe"

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

If I subscribe for scripthash changes with method  `blockchain.scripthash.subscribe` I receive by socket statuses. The reason why I subscribe - I want to know when and how my balance has been changed. Can I fetch new balance from the status? What really useful information can I fetch from a status?

My subscription request:

```
{
   jsonrpc: '2.0',
   method: "blockchain.scripthash.subscribe",
   params: 
     ['a3eacd2b04a0cb761ca944d7d449a53b6c030c6081398fc13b5b1fd537c20547'],
   id: 1,
}
```

Response:

```
{ jsonrpc: '2.0',
  result:
   'ad5423815bdaa3054efa39130d92cf876100c9da37e5b5105a7abcca2882f4cc',
  id: 1 }
```

Notification when I send some coins to another wallet:

```
{ jsonrpc: '2.0',
  result:
   'ad5423815bdaa3054efa39130d92cf876100c9da37e5b5105a7abcca2882f4cc',
  id: 1 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-basics.html#status) status is just a hash of all you transactions, ordered in a specific manner.

As long as it is a **hash** you can't get any useful information besides "it was changed". This means that there were some changes in your transactions (new transaction appeared or transaction was confirmed). Thats it.